# fixfoot package crashes when footnote contains enumerate enviironment

Tags: xetex, texlive

I'm trying to do something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixfoot}

\begin{document}

\DeclareFixedFootnote{\footone}
  {This works OK}
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\foottwo}
  {%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This crashes
  \end{enumerate}
  }

Some text\footone
Some text\foottwo

\end{document}
```

Running xelatex in TeXLive on Windows I get

```
./test.tex:14: Undefined control sequence.
\enumerate ...ce \@enumdepth \@ne \edef \@enumctr 
                                                  {enum\romannumeral \the \@...
l.14   }

./test.tex:14: Undefined control sequence.
\enumerate ...dafter \list \csname label\@enumctr 
                                                  \endcsname {\usecounter \@...
l.14   }

./test.tex:14: Undefined control sequence.
\list ... \@listdepth \endcsname \def \@itemlabel 
                                                  {#1}\let \makelabel \@mkla...
l.14   }

./test.tex:14: Argument of \label has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14   }

Runaway argument?
./test.tex:14: Paragraph ended before \label was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.14   }

)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 14.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> test.tex
```

(Line 14 is the end of the definition of `\foottwo.`)

I guess I need to `\protect` something to make this work, but I can't figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fixfoot` package uses the `.aux` file for saving the fixed footnote texts, so this requires protecting fragile commands.

You can solve your issue by using `\unexpanded` (or putting `\protect` before every fragile command, among which `\begin`, `\end` and `\item`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixfoot}

\begin{document}

\DeclareFixedFootnote{\footone}
  {This works OK}
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\foottwo}
  {%
  \unexpanded{\begin{enumerate}
  \item This crashes
  \end{enumerate}}%
  }

Some text\footone
Some text\foottwo

\end{document}
```

Another strategy would be defining

```
\newcommand{\XDeclareFixedFootnote}[2]{%
   \DeclareFixedFootnote{#1}{\unexpanded{#2}}%
}
```

and using `\XDeclareFixedFootnote` throughout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixfoot}

\newcommand{\XDeclareFixedFootnote}[2]{%
   \DeclareFixedFootnote{#1}{\unexpanded{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\XDeclareFixedFootnote{\footone}
  {This works OK}
\XDeclareFixedFootnote{\foottwo}
  {%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This crashes
  \end{enumerate}
  }

Some text\footone
Some text\foottwo

\end{document}
```

You may also want to look at the `sepfootnotes` package.

Comment: `sepfoonotes` doesn't seem to have the key functionality I want, which is to automatically print the footnote text exactly once on each page and print just the footnotemark for other references from that page. The other solutions work fine.